# JQuery or any other client side scripting to get client windows username

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

In my application I need to authenticate end consumer using his windows credentials. Is there any way to retrieve windows credentials(user name & password) using any client side scripting?

I am preferably looking for jquery or javascript to do this.

Comment: Simple answer.  No.  You shouldn't even be considering this.

Answer (score 1):

No, as this would be a major security issue.

Comment: If not password , can we get the logged on user name

Comment: No.  You cannot get this information for obvious reasons.

Comment: You can push it to your client from the server, but not vice versa.